# SQL запрос_вычленить из базы цифры

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

В первой таблице, где данные вида `t_info_u129279_cpn_1`, название столбца `dump`, а во второй, где просто номера, название столбца `user_id`
то есть уникальный ID пользователя после `_u  (t_info_u129279_cpn_1)`, номер компании после `_cpn_ (t_info_u129279_cpn_1)`

Мне нужно сопоставить со второй таблицей номера компании и номера пользователей. Проблема ещё в том, что данные в первой таблице разные: какие-то строки содержат `t_info_u129279_cpn_1`, какие-то `t_info_cpn_1_u129279 delphi`

Подскажите, как написать правильный код в SQL? Нужно как-то вычленить цифры из базы?

Comment: А БД все таки MySQL или postgress. А то тут `like` нужен, а он подчеркивание за любой символ считает, заменять надо. А функции замены в разных БД разные ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для MySQL примерно так (проверять не на чем, вы базу готовую не предоставили).

```
select *
  from Table1 A
  join Table2 B
    on replace(concat(A.dump,'-'),'_','-') like concat('%-u',B.user_id,'-%')
```

Приходится менять подчеркивание на тире, потому как в `like` оно обозначает 1 любой символ. В Postgress то же по идее должно работать, функция замены называется так же. Надеюсь для `cpn` сами сделаете по аналогии.

**UPD**: По рекомендациям [@msi](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/2339/msi) последнюю строку можно упростить до:

```
 concat(A.dump,'-') like concat('%|_u',B.user_id,'|_%') ESCAPE '|'
```

Comment: Замену делать не нужно, если использовать escape-символ.

Comment: @msi, вот кстати какой, я ходу не нашел как он задается

Comment: @Mike, например, `A.dump like concat('%|_u',B.user_id,'|_%') ESCAPE '|'`

Comment: Спасибо большое! все работает